# Positioning of two inputs on the same line

Tags: css, css-float

On http://www.southdevonaonb.org.uk/cordialemapping/ in any of the tabs under "Wembury" I have two inputs on the same line - the first is a check box and the second is an image (blue information icon).

I want both inputs to float to the right of the parent div so that vertically they all appear inline.

This is the HTML:

```
Letterbox locations and results
<input type="image" align="right" id="info-image" class="info-image" src="images/info.png" title="Click for more information about this layer" onclick="layer0()" value='Info'/>
<input type="checkbox" id="layer0" onclick="toggleLayer(0)" unchecked><br />
```

And the CSS:

```
.info-image{
float:right !important;
display:inline !important;
}

#info-image{
float:right !important;
display:inline !important;
}
```

What I have tried:

I have given the input image a class and ID and tried forcing it to float to the right as well as trying the display tag for a similar effect, but with no luck. How can I achieve this?

Screenshot here of what I am trying to achieve:

http://www.southdevonaonb.org.uk/cordialemapping/help/screenshot1.png

Comment: I believe the input tag is an inline element. What happens when you leave out your styling?

Comment: One thing you can do to get control on the 'bock' level is add `display:block` to the elements. You may have more luck with that.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot image of how you want it to appear? - @Riverbum75

Comment: Adding 'block' didn't make any difference... I don't have enough 'reputation' yet to add images, but I've put a screenshot here - http://www.southdevonaonb.org.uk/cordialemapping/help/screenshot1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure as to how you want it to appear, but from the things perceived, here is the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/DFSLZ/).

The HTML:

```
<input id="info-image" class="info-image" align="right" type="image" src="images/info.png" title="Click for more information about this layer" onclick="layer100()" value="Info">
<br>
<input id="layer100" type="checkbox" unchecked="" onclick="toggleLayer(100)" style="margin-right: -15px; margin-top: 7px;">
```

The CSS:

```
.info-image{
float:right !important;
display:inline !important;
}

#info-image{
float:right !important;
display:inline !important;
}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

I just got your screenshot notification and have made some edits.

The HTML:

```
<div>
<p style="float: left; width: 70%;">Parish boundary line Parish boundary line</p>
<p>
<input align="right" type="image" value="Info" onclick="layer100()" title="Click for more information about this layer" src="images/info.png" class="info-image" id="info-image">
<input type="checkbox" unchecked="" onclick="toggleLayer(100)" id="layer100">
</p>
</div>
<div>
<p style="float: left; width: 70%;">Parish boundary line Parish boundary line</p>
<p>
<input align="right" type="image" value="Info" onclick="layer100()" title="Click for more information about this layer" src="images/info.png" class="info-image" id="info-image">
<input type="checkbox" unchecked="" onclick="toggleLayer(100)" id="layer100">
</p>
</div>
<div>
<p style="float: left; width: 70%;">Parish boundary line Parish boundary line</p>
<p>
<input align="right" type="image" value="Info" onclick="layer100()" title="Click for more information about this layer" src="images/info.png" class="info-image" id="info-image">
<input type="checkbox" unchecked="" onclick="toggleLayer(100)" id="layer100">
</p>
</div>
```

You need to just need to remove your `<p>` tag which has the checkbox and the image and replicate the full `<p>` tag with the `<div>` code provided above. I hope this helps now.

Comment: Thanks... but that's the same as what I already have... unless it makes a difference if you define the id and/or class before the other values?

Comment: I have edited the code on the basis of your screenshot in my updated answer. Hope this helps now - @Riverbum75

Comment: Thanks... I see the two input elements were inside a <p> tag and therefore inheriting its value?

Comment: Yes. As per the screenshot provided by you, they should be independent of each other with one container holding their independence. - @Riverbum75

Comment: I hope you are satisfied with the answer. - @Riverbum75

Answer (score 0):

try this, u have to set the right of the image

> ## info-image{
>
> float:right !important;
>
> display:inline !important;
>
> **right: 4px;**/*OR// right: 40px;*/
> }

Comment: Thanks... but that didn't make any difference at all. I'm guessing that it is inheriting a style, but surely using !important should force the id/class specific style and override that?